# GeoServer Manager: how to change description of stores?

Tags: geoserver, shapefile, geoserver-manager

Here is my code to upload a new layer from a shapefile (zipped):

```
boolean exists = reader.existsDatastore(workspaceName, storeName);
  if ( !exists ) {
        File shapeFile = new File( "path/to/zipFile.zip" );
        boolean published = publisher.publishShp(workspaceName, 
              storeName, "TheLayerName", shapeFile, "EPSG:4326", "");
  }
```

All is fine, but I need to set the "Description" of the new Store and maybe the "Create spatial index if missing/outdated" value too.

After run this code, I go to GeoServer and select "Stores". On "Edit Vector Data Source" screen I can see the "Description" field is empty.

After googling a lot I discover the `GSCoverageEncoder layerEncoder = new GSCoverageEncoder();` method, but I've tried many ways and have no success ( with `configureCoverage` ).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    GeoServerRESTReader reader;
    GeoServerRESTStoreManager storeManager;

    reader = new GeoServerRESTReader(RESTURL, RESTUSER, RESTPW);
    storeManager = new GeoServerRESTStoreManager( new URL(RESTURL), RESTUSER, RESTPW); 

    RESTDataStore rds = reader.getDatastore(workSpaceName, storeName);

    GSDirectoryOfShapefilesDatastoreEncoder update = new GSDirectoryOfShapefilesDatastoreEncoder(rds);
    update.setDescription("New Description goes here"); 
    update.setEnabled(true); 
    update.setCharset(Charset.forName("UTF-8")); 
    update.setCreateSpatialIndex(true);   

    storeManager.update(workSpaceName, update);
```